# How to deal with double numbers in forms in ASP.Net MVC 5.2.7 (.Net Framework)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, razor

I am currently having a problem with the treatment of double numbers in form when using asp-mvc generated views. 
Let me show my model Eleve, here the field I am focusing on is Moyenne (relative annotations are the last ones I tried from previous research) :

```
public class Eleve
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nom { get; set; }
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = false, DataFormatString = "{0:P0}")]
    [RegularExpression(@"[0-9]+(\.[0-9][0-9]?)?$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid rate")]
    public double Moyenne { get; set; }
}
```

Controller is the one auto-generated by asp mvc 5 using Entity Framework.
Relevant part of the view :

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Moyenne, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Moyenne, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control decimal-small inline" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Moyenne, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
</div>
```

When I submit the form while using a not-integer input, I get an error message telling me (in French) that the value is not correct :
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RK383.jpg) 
In practice, I would need to be able to use numbers with 2 decimals after the separator. For now, only integers are accepted. It seems the solutions I found are outdated, or I missed something.
Thanks for your help !

Comment: correct me if i'm wrong - but in france, the official decimal separator is a _comma_, not a dot? have you tried typing `3,2` instead? what you have here seems to be a typical locale-problem.

Comment: Yes, I tried both since I suspected it to be the problem, it gives the same result. On a sidenote, your point is true most of the time but when it comes to using a computer, French people mostly use "." as a separator.

Answer (score 1):

ModelState is also validated against some  CultureInfo parameters. Since using french,
the decimal separator is "," so you see 0 in the breakPoint.

Here is a workarround (using autogenerated Controller):

The Idea is to change the change the CultureInfo in the GET and restore it in the POST.

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create( Eleve eleve)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
      db.Eleve.Add(eleve);
      db.SaveChanges();
      return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    
    CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("fr-FR");
    return View(eleve);
}

// 
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:0.00}")]
```

Answer (score -1):

Hello Benoit essayes comme ça

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:#,##0.00#}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = false)]
public double? Moyenne{ get; set; }
```

tu peux aussi essayer cette regex:

```
^-?\d(.\d+)?[^.]
```

Comment: Hello and thanks for your answer. I tried both at once, and this time I still got an error message, "Invalid rate". Did you try it yourself ?